# T-SQL: Wild Card as table name alias in select statement possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is more of a curiosity than an actual applied question. Say you have a statement with multiple joins such as:

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    b.salary,
    c.x

FROM 
    [table1] a

INNER JOIN [table2] b
    ON a.key = b.key

INNER JOIN [table3] c
    ON b.key = c.key
```

Now, say you were to make several more joins to other tables whose schema was unfamiliar, however you know:

- the keys on which to make the join
- that *several* of those tables has a column with the the name 'x'.

Is it possible to select 'x' from all tables that contain it, without explicitly referring to the table alias. So it would ave a similar results as this (if it were possible)

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    b.salary,
    *.x
...
```

Comment: Think like a database developer. Say we allow that, across all tables included. Then we're returning 5 columns, all called x, and how do you know which is which?

Comment: I am trying to find out if it is possible to select several columns with the same name over multiple joined tables without explicitly prefixing the table name (or alias) in the select statement. @Penguat I'm assuming it is bad practice but curious to its possibility.

Comment: You may be able to pull all the table/columns from `sys.columns`, and then build your sql accordingly.

Comment: @penguat - But this is possible anyway. You can do `SELECT a.x, b.x, c.x`. SQL Server does not enforce that the column names must be unique on an outer `select`

Comment: Martin's answer is correct :) I was trying to fill you in with a possible *why*

Comment: @martinSmith but in that case you know which order the columns are in - you have specified it.

Comment: @penguat - This is allowed as well. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1) A(X) JOIN (SELECT 1) B(X) ON A.X = B.X`. i.e. if you use `*` on a join where multiple columns are called `X` you get the same problem but it isn't disallowed.

Comment: @MartinSmith so it is! Good point. At that, I'm left wondering myself why it's not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I had my doubts that it would be plausible. I will mark @MartinSmith answer as correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this isn't possible.

You can use `a.*` to get all columns from `a` but it is not valid to use a wildcard as the table name.

Answer (score 2):

@Martin Smith is correct that you can't use `*.x` and refer to columns from multiple tables. There is however a way to write a query that shows all columns `x` from tables where they exist without breaking if one or more of the tables do not have such column. It's a rather complicated way that (mis)uses scope resolution.

Lets say that some of the tables (`b` and `d` in the example) have a column named `x`, while some others (`c` here) do not have such column. Then you can replace `INNER` joins with `CROSS APPLY` and `LEFT` joins with `OUTER APPLY` and a query with:

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    a.salary,
    b.x AS bx,
    'WITHOUT column x' AS cx,
    d.x AS dx
FROM 
    a
  INNER JOIN b 
      ON a.aid = b.aid
  LEFT JOIN c 
      ON a.aid = c.aid
  LEFT JOIN d 
      ON a.aid = d.aid ;
```

would be written as:

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    a.salary,
    bx,
    cx,
    dx
FROM 
  ( SELECT a.*,
           'WITHOUT column x' AS x
    FROM a
  ) a
CROSS APPLY
  ( SELECT x AS bx
    FROM b
    WHERE a.aid = b.aid
  ) b
OUTER APPLY
  ( SELECT x AS cx
    FROM c 
    WHERE a.aid = c.aid
  ) c
OUTER APPLY
  ( SELECT x AS dx
    FROM d
    WHERE a.aid = d.aid
  ) d ;
```

Tested at SQL-Server 2008: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b742/1)**